# What should be a normal throughput of data from an alienware 17 across a network to usb 2.0

Tags: networking, hard-drive, wireless-networking, usb

I am transferring large movie files from my alienware 17 computer over a wireless network connected to my usb 2.0 wdtv live usb connection to a 2 TB Fantom Green usb 2.0 drive.  I typically get around 10 MB per second transfer speed.  Is this normal, or can it be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details ofyour hardware, that is both a very good speed and one which probably can be improved, but not without throwing money or changing the solution.

Its good because you are pushing > 80 megabits/sec (ie 10 MB) through a Wireless connection - that is not to be sneezed at - and this is most likely where the bottleneck is occuring.   You can test that by replacing the wireless connection with a cable which should increase the speed.   (You may be able to improve the wireless speed as well - its definately possible to get much faster then 80 megabits/sec over wireless, but it would require a low noise environment and very good - and newish WIFI hardware)

From doing some Googling I see its probable the computer can (assuming it is the same model - one with 802.11ac wifi) push higher speeds, however the WDTV specs only claim (in small print) Wireless-N - Wireless N can have different speeds, and as they did not advertise the feature I assume its using the lowest "up to 150 megabit" speed - if this is the case, 10MB/sec is very good going across that type of connection.

USB2 connections can transfer up to 480 megabit - about 40MB / second, and a typical hard drive can sustain more then 40MB per second - so that is another bottleck.